# is it possible to do it in one query with dynamic table name without prepare statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a survey record table which I want to count the latest survey recoders with field 'complete' is''Y', while the latest  survay name is in another table with the createdate, that's mean, the table name is dynamic,

```
select 'complete' count(*)  
from( 
  select 'survey_name' 
  from survey 
  Where active=''Y'' 
  order by cratedate desc 
  limit 1
  )
```

but it cant work

**record** table: (name is dynamic)

```
id | complete | submitdate
```

**survey** table:

```
survay_name | active | cratedate
```

I knew it should be done by prepare statement, but my system (joomla + plotalot) only accept one query.

Comment: What is the link between the survey table and the record table?

Comment: the problem is there is no Link between those 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add '**id**' column in your **Survey** table
**Of Course**, the ID must link between SURVEY and RECORD table

then,, you can use below query

```
SELECT COUNT(r.complete) as complete, s.survay_name, s.createDate
FROM survey s
LEFT JOIN record r ON s.id = r.id
WHERE s.active = 'Y' AND r.complete = 'Y'
```

Comment: hi AKZhang, thanks for reply but the table is create by another system , So I can Not change the table structure.

Comment: Hi @eagle then you can't link these two table.. if you want to get COUNT, then you won't be able to get the survay_name.. or, did you have another table which link between the ID and survay_Name?

Comment: No, I think should use subquery or prepare statement.